# SSIS - Set up MySQL Connection Manager (has SSH Tunneling)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis

I want to connect MySQL data source by SSIS and try to set up connection. The MySQL Connection use SSH Tunneling.

I've tried to create MySQL Connection Manager with this configuration below, but it still facing error like this :
[image]

[image: Set Up MySQL Connection]

Instead, with MySQL Editor tool was success to connect the server (such as SQLYog).

[image: MySQL tab - SQLYog]
[image: SSH tab - SQLYog]

I confused there was configuration or step which I missed.Any advice will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is notoriously picky and judging by the elapsed 6 months here there are no real answers.
I *have* to use SSIS at work but every opportunity I get to replace a data pipeline with something else I do so. Take a look at Talend, it works.

As for your problem here try to download and install the MySql ODBC connector from the MySQl site get that installed, and setup the ODBC source on your OS.

[MYSQL ODBC connector download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Then in SSIS you should be able to create a connection manager to the ODBC driver and (MYSQL)source.

Alternatively, in my .NET code(c# or f#) I think its 3 lines to define the connection string and get some data out! Go figure.